# How to know the number of positions just deleted in the list?

Tags: python

I have a probleme with this excercise
I have a list of duplicate numbers like this and i don't known how to give the position of the numbers have just been deleted

```
l1 = [12, 12, 3, 18, 4, 5, 3, 16, 14, 15, 12]
```

I expecting the result will be like this

```
3 numbers have been removed
12 was in position 1
3 was in position 6
12 was in position 10
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: Welcome! Please show us your attempt.

Comment: The list doesn't know where values were deleted from it - it doesn't even know *whether* anything was ever deleted from it.  All it contains is its current set of values.  You'd have to track this information yourself, separately from the list.

Comment: _For example_, you can retain the previous context of the list.  Then when required, you will compare the two lists. and get your results.

Comment: 1) Create an empty set and an empty list 2) Iterate over each index and element of the original list using `enumerate`. 3) if the current element does not exist in the set, add it to the new list and to the set 4) if the element exists in the set don't add it to the new list and `print(f"{element} was  in position {index}")`. 5) Once the loop is over, the new list will contain only the unique elements of the original list. Exercise for you: Implement that.

Comment: Sorry for bad writing. This is the first time i post a question in Stack Overflow, i tried many ways like the loop or the condition, but it seem not a way to solve it. I really stuck at this excercise

Comment: show us your code and where you got stuck then. In my comment you have the steps you need to implement to solve your question. Go point by point nd if you don't know how to do what it says look at a tutorial how to do that specific thing.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: This can be slightly simplified in modern Python thanks to `dict`s being insertion-ordered. So you can just use a `dict` for the processing, which will provide *both* `O(1)` lookup/insertion *and* insertion ordering, then call `list` on it at the end if you a proper `list` (calling `list` on a `dict` returns a `list` of the `dict`'s keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While iterating, you can keep track of which numbers have been visited before, then store that number along with its index somewhere to report it later. Only add the numbers which haven't been visited before to the final list(basically creating a new list without duplicate values):

```py
def delete_duplicates_and_report(lst: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    seen = set[int]()
    deleted_items: list[tuple[int, int]] = []
    res: list[int] = []
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        if item in seen:
            deleted_items.append((i, item))
        else:
            res.append(item)
            seen.add(item)

    # reporting
    print(f"{len(deleted_items)} numbers have been removed")
    for i, item in deleted_items:
        print(f"{item} was in position {i}")
    return res

l1 = [12, 12, 3, 18, 4, 5, 3, 16, 14, 15, 12]
filtered_lst = delete_duplicates_and_report(l1)
print(filtered_lst)
```

output:

```
3 numbers have been removed
12 was in position 1
3 was in position 6
12 was in position 10
[12, 3, 18, 4, 5, 16, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the positions of duplicates, we can readily obtain that info using `sorted` and `itertools.groupby`.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l1 = [12, 12, 3, 18, 4, 5, 3, 16, 14, 15, 12]
```

Now, let's map our list of values to tuples containing the values and their indices. Doing this lets us sort the list by value without losing information about their indices in the original list.

```
>>> l2 = [(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(l1)]
>>> l3 = sorted(l2, key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> l3
[(3, 2), (3, 6), (4, 4), (5, 5), (12, 0), (12, 1), (12, 10), (14, 8), (15, 9), (16, 7), (18, 3)]
```

Having first sorted (this is not optional) we can group these values. We can convert this to a dictionary to better visualize the information: each unique element of the list along with the indices each is located at in the original list.

```
>>> g = groupby(l3, key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> d = {k: list(e[1] for e in v) for k, v in g}
>>> d
{3: [2, 6], 4: [4], 5: [5], 12: [0, 1, 10], 14: [8], 15: [9], 16: [7], 18: [3]}
```

Anywhere the list is longer than one element, a duplicate exists. Let's get rid of those with the `if` clause of our dictionary comprehension. We then discard the first index as that would be the one "kept" and we get the discarded indices with the key being the value deleted.

```
>>> d2 = {k: v[1:] for k, v in d.items() if len(v) > 1}
>>> d2
{3: [6], 12: [1, 10]}
```

This can be readily used to print your end output by using a list comprehension to "flip" the dictionary into a list of tuples. Then we just need to iterate over that list and print.

```
>>> l4 = sorted(
...   [(k, idx) 
...    for k, v in d2.items() 
...    for idx in v], 
...   key=lambda x: x[1]
... )
>>> l4
[(12, 1), (3, 6), (12, 10)]
>>> for v, idx in l4:
...   print(f"{v} was in position {idx}")
...
12 was in position 1
3 was in position 6
12 was in position 10
```